# What does it mean that Groovy Category use is confined to the current thread?

Tags: multithreading, class, groovy, categories

I found the following statement in the book **Groovy In Action, 2nd Edition**:

> Category use is confined to the current thread

What does this statement actually mean ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means you are able to call methods added via category class in the same thread only. Consider following example:

```
class StringUtils {
    static String transform(String source) {
        return source.toUpperCase().reverse().substring(0, source.length() / 2 as int)
    }
}

use (StringUtils) {
    println "Lorem ipsum".transform()
}
```

In this example we are adding `String.transform()` method via category. Running this example produces following output:

```
MUSPI
```

In this example we have used category class in the `main` thread and we have called `String.transform()` method in the `main` thread as well.

Now let's change this example a little bit and let's call `String.transform()` method outside `main` thread by calling it in the newly started thread:

```
class StringUtils {
    static String transform(String source) {
        return source.toUpperCase().reverse().substring(0, source.length() / 2 as int)
    }
}

use (StringUtils) {
    Thread.start {
        println "Lorem ipsum".transform()
    }
}
```

We have used `StringUtil` category class in the `main` thread and we call this method from `Thread-1` thread. Let's see what happens when we run it:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.String.transform() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:58)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaClassSite.call(PojoMetaClassSite.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)
    at script$_run_closure1$_closure2.doCall(script.groovy:9)
    at script$_run_closure1$_closure2.doCall(script.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:414)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:408)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.run(Closure.java:495)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

An exception is thrown, because `String.transform()` does not exist in scope of `Thread-1` thread - it exists only in `main` thread.

But let's assume that we have to make this method available in `Thread-1` thread scope. We can make it happened by defining `use(StringUtils){}` inside the `Thread-1` block, e.g.

```
class StringUtils {
    static String transform(String source) {
        return source.toUpperCase().reverse().substring(0, source.length() / 2 as int)
    }
}

Thread.start {
    use(StringUtils) {
        println "Lorem ipsum".transform()
    }
}
```

Now everything is fine - category usage block is defined inside `Thread-1` and we call `String.transform()` method from the same thread. Running this example produces expected output to the console:

```
MUSPI
```

This is what

> Category use is confined to the current thread

means in practice.

#### But how this method gets called?

When we call:

```
"Lorem ipsum".transform()
```

from the above example, following Groovy method handles invocation of `transform()` method:

```
groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(Class sender, Object object, String methodName, Object[] originalArguments, boolean isCallToSuper, boolean fromInsideClass)
```

You can find it at line 1044 (Groovy 2.4.12). `transform()` method does not exist in class `String` so Groovy has to find its implementation somewhere else. In this case the method is found in line 1055:

```
MetaMethod method = null;
if (CLOSURE_CALL_METHOD.equals(methodName) && object instanceof GeneratedClosure) {
    method = getMethodWithCaching(sender, "doCall", arguments, isCallToSuper);
}
```

Most important part of this method is line 1283:

```
if (!isCallToSuper && GroovyCategorySupport.hasCategoryInCurrentThread()) {
    return getMethodWithoutCaching(sender, methodName, MetaClassHelper.convertToTypeArray(arguments), isCallToSuper);
} else {
    ....
}
```

`GroovyCategorySupport.hasCategoryInCurrentThread()` checks if the category is used in the current thread (`ThreadLocal` is used in this case).

If you trace what happens next you will get to the `MetaClassImpl` line 690 where `getMethods(Class sender, String name, boolean isCallToSuper)` is located. In line 706 this method calls:

```
List used = GroovyCategorySupport.getCategoryMethods(name);
```

And this is the final part that actually finds the method by its name in the category class. Later it checks if the method is static and if it expects a parameter with a valid type (`String` in this case).

Comment: @Szimon thanks for a great explanation. Then it means that applying a category class in this case does not alter the metaclass of the String class, otherwise the methods from StringUtils would be available also for String instances in other threads at the moment when the current thread is uses the category class. Then what is the mechanism used internally to make the StringUtils methods available to String class in this case?

Comment: @SurenAznauryan Groovy has a class called `GroovyCategorySupport` that provides helper methods for invoking methods added by a category class. Methods that are added via category are stored in `ThreadLocal` and this class ensures that you are invoking method from the current thread. Those methods are not added to the e.g. `String` class - when you invoke a method that does not exist in the class, Groovy searches for it in metaclass, categories etc. It's so called Meta-Object Protocol (MOP) in Groovy.

Comment: @SurenAznauryan I've updated the answer with more detailed explanation.

Comment: One more thing. If category class method uses static variable from category class, then using that category method from many threads can lead to a race condition, right ? Is there anything preventing race condition in Groovy in that case ?

Comment: Yes, there are a few options: 1) Don't use static variables, 2) If you have to use static variable, make it final and never mutate it's state (might be problematic with mutable objects), 3) use `ThreadLocal` that bounds variable with the caller's thread (multiple threads won't override values available to other threads), 4) synchronize access to the static field if there is no other option.

Comment: Ok , so nothing special to Categories, the safety mechanism is the usual one. Thank you very much